# Changing shapefile longitude from -180-180 to 0-360 in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

I have a world shapefile. The shapefile which I have has Greenwich as the prime meridian. I got the world shapefile from this [link](https://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.zip).

I have to convert this shapefile into a similar world shapefile as shown below. The longitudes of output shapefile should range from 0 to 359 where the latitude remains the same.[image]

Is there some way to do this thing in ArcGIS?

My output shapefile should look something like as shown above.

Comment: The figure doesn't seem to illustrate your conversion request.  It's still latitude +/- 90 and longitude -/+ 180, and not 0-360

Answer (score 1):

It is unusual to be trying to define the longitude from 0 to 359. Longitude is customarily referred to as either -180 to +180 or 180W to 180E.

That being said, you should investigate the [Projections and Transformations Toolbox](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/an-overview-of-projections-and-transformations-toolset.htm) in ArcGIS. If you already have a layer in your desired output projection you can use [Project](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/project.htm) tool. If you don't already have another layer in the desired projection then I'm not sure which exact tool(s) from this toolbox you would need to use.

Comment: Actually I am trying to generate spatial correlation plots similar to the picture I have attached in my question. That's why I need a shapefile in that format which makes my thing easy. Also, I just want to know whether it can be done or not.

Comment: This is more of a clip-n-shift task than a projection task. I would construct a two-cell fishnet, from -200,-100 to +200,+100 (broken from 0,-100 to 0,+100), Intersect with that, add 360 to the X values in grid 1, then Dissolve on all the original FC's attributes. You might need to manually snap the eastern edge of Antarctica to the western landmass, since there's sometimes a sliver gap near the antemeridian.